# MySQLdump on specific db date

Tags: mysql, backup, windows, mysqldump

I'm new in here and i don't really know where to start but here is my concern. I need to backyp a MySQL DB running under windows once a week. For e.g every friday i need to backup and transfer to another server the MYSQL DB created on the Thursday.

I have the DB created with the following naming : YYMMDD_HHMM_dbname.

i've tried loads of mysqldump options so far but can't get that specific DB that i would like too.

I would higly appreciate if you guys could help me on that.

With thks..

Comment: Are you running on Linux? If so, you want to use `cron`. The people on serverfault will be able to help you with that

Comment: OK the database you want to backup is running under Windows. Is the other server running MySQL in Windows or Linux ???

Comment: Hi,Yes the Db is under windows and the other server is under windows as well.

Comment: +1 for the `mysqldump in Windows` puzzle !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is the following:

- STEP 01 : Create a SQL script that will write a Windows batch file
- STEP 02 : Execute the SQL script to create the Windows batch file
- STEP 03 : Execute the Windows batch file

## STEP 01

First let's create the SQL file. The SQL file will have these rules

- Find the Last Thursday as of Today
- Locate the database
- If today is Thursday and you run this script, then pick DB for the Thursday before that
- Echo the Windows batch file, starting with `@echo off`

Here is the Windows batch file

```
SET @dborigin='rolando';
SET @today = DATE(NOW());
SET @this_thurs = @today - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(@today) DAY - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
SET @ut1 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@this_thurs);
SET @ut2 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@today);
SET @last_thurs = @this_thurs - INTERVAL IF(@ut1=@ut2,1,0) WEEK;
SET @user = 'root';
SET @pass = 'password';
SET @dumpfile = 'C:\\TransferDB.sql';
SELECT '@echo off';
SET @SQL='SELECT CONCAT(''mysqldump -u'',@user,'' -p'',@pass,'' --routines --triggers '',db,'' > '',@dumpfile) mysqldump_command FROM (SELECT schema_name db FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE LEFT(schema_name,6) = DATE_FORMAT(@last_thurs,''%y%m%d'') AND RIGHT(schema_name,LENGTH(@dborigin))=@dborigin) A';
PREPARE s FROM @SQL; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

Save the SQL script as `C:\Make_mysqldump.sql`

## STEP 02 and 03

```
C:\> mysql -uroot -ppass -AN < C:\Make_mysqldump.sql > C:\Exec_mysqldump.bat
C:\> C:\Exec_mysqldump.bat
```

I will demonstrate Steps 01 and 02

## DEMONSTRATION

Here the databases on my Windows machine

```
mysql> show databases;
+---------------------+
| Database            |
+---------------------+
| information_schema  |
| 131128_1234_rolando |
| 131129_1234_rolando |
| 131130_1234_rolando |
| 131203_1234_rolando |
| 131204_1234_rolando |
| 131205_1234_rolando |
| 131206_1234_rolando |
| alisha              |
| beercan             |
| musicdata           |
| mysql               |
| performance_schema  |
| test                |
+---------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the text file:

```
C:\>type Make_mysqldump.sql
SET @dborigin='rolando';
SET @today = DATE(NOW());
SET @this_thurs = @today - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(@today) DAY - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
SET @ut1 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@this_thurs);
SET @ut2 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@today);
SET @last_thurs = @this_thurs - INTERVAL IF(@ut1=@ut2,1,0) WEEK;
SET @user = 'root';
SET @pass = 'password';
SET @dumpfile = 'C:\\TransferDB.sql';
SELECT '@echo off';
SET @SQL='SELECT CONCAT(''mysqldump -u'',@user,'' -p'',@pass,'' --routines --triggers '',db,'' > '',@dumpfile) mysqldump
_command FROM (SELECT schema_name db FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE LEFT(schema_name,6) = DATE_FORMAT(@last_thur
s,''%y%m%d'') AND RIGHT(schema_name,LENGTH(@dborigin))=@dborigin) A';
PREPARE s FROM @SQL; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

Here is the creation of the batch file and its contents:

```
C:\>mysql -AN < C:\Make_mysqldump.sql > C:\Exec_mysqldump.bat

C:\>type C:\Exec_mysqldump.bat
@echo off
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --routines --triggers 131129_1234_rolando > C:\\TransferDB.sql

C:\>
```

**CAVEAT** : I'll leave the rest to your imagination to run the mysqldump and execute `C:\TransferDB.sql` on the target DB server.

## Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-12-06 18:51 EST

Here is a crazy idea requiring some elbow grease

## STEP #1

Remove the first line of `C:\Make_mysqldump.sql` do it looks like this:

```
SET @today = DATE(NOW());
SET @this_thurs = @today - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(@today) DAY - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
SET @ut1 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@this_thurs);
SET @ut2 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@today);
SET @last_thurs = @this_thurs - INTERVAL IF(@ut1=@ut2,1,0) WEEK;
SET @user = 'root';
SET @pass = 'password';
SET @dumpfile = 'C:\\TransferDB.sql';
SELECT '@echo off';
SET @SQL='SELECT CONCAT(''mysqldump -u'',@user,'' -p'',@pass,'' --routines --triggers '',db,'' > '',@dumpfile) mysqldump_command FROM (SELECT schema_name db FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE LEFT(schema_name,6) = DATE_FORMAT(@last_thurs,''%y%m%d'') AND RIGHT(schema_name,LENGTH(@dborigin))=@dborigin) A';
PREPARE s FROM @SQL; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

## STEP #2

Create a new batch file (Call it `C:\MakeBackupJob.bat`) whose sole purpose is to make a dborigin variable and append the rest. It should have these lines:

```
@echo off
echo set @dborigin='%1'; > C:\MakeJob_%1.sql
type C:\Make_mysqldump.sql >> C:\MakeJob_%1.sql
```

## EPILOGUE

To use `C:\MakeBackupJob.bat`, simply specify the database tag name. Suppose the databases are `rolando`,`pamela`,`dominique`,`diamond`. Simply run the following:

```
C:
cd \
MakeBackupJob.bat rolando
MakeBackupJob.bat pamela
MakeBackupJob.bat dominique
MakeBackupJob.bat rolando
```

You should have 4 SQL files in C:\

```
MakeJob_rolando.sql
MakeJob_pamela.sql
MakeJob_dominique.sql
MakeJob_diamond.sql
```

Now, run the following:

```
echo @echo off  > C:\Exec_mysqldump.bat
C:\>mysql -AN < C:\MakeJob_rolando.sql   >> C:\Exec_mysqldump.bat
C:\>mysql -AN < C:\MakeJob_pamela.sql    >> C:\Exec_mysqldump.bat
C:\>mysql -AN < C:\MakeJob_dominique.sql >> C:\Exec_mysqldump.bat
C:\>mysql -AN < C:\MakeJob_diamond.sql   >> C:\Exec_mysqldump.bat
```

Now, `C:\Exec_mysqldump.bat` contains 4 mysqldumps to separate files.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Well explained!

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the explanation. I'll give a try straight away and revert back.

Comment: Hi Rolanda,I've tried it, but it come up with an empty bat file with only line @echo off .. What could be wrong?

Comment: Look over the query and see if it matches the database names. If it does not invade privacy, please post your `SHOW DATABASES;` and SQL script you made (hide your passwords).

Comment: My mistake..I got it to work..there was an invisible character hidden in the text file. Now it's working perfectly. Thank you very much for your sharing..i owe you one ;) Have a good one..

Comment: Hi Rolando, Well..it's working but i forgot to ask.. what if i have multiple Dbs on that particular day ? how can i specify a different output .sql name? as for now, for e.g i have 4 dbs and all four lines generated in the bat file have all the same output name .sql..

Comment: Hi Rolando,got everything working. Thanks again for the help. Appreciate :)