# Move a MySQL 5.5 database to a server running MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, migration, mysql-5.1

I have a backup of a MySQL database (using InnoDB) from a Windows machine that was running MySQL 5.5. The Windows machine is no longer available and now I need to import the backup into an Ubuntu box running MySQL 5.1.73. Is this possible? Any hints on how/where to copy the files?

Most of the info I find is about "upgrading" from 5.1 to 5.5 but in my case I need to go the opposite way.

Comment: Is mysql still up and running on the Windows machine ?

Comment: The Windows machine is no longer available.

Comment: If you can move that folder to another Windows and fire up MySQL on it, you could then apply my answer (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81602/877)

Answer (score 1):

I have a script to move MySQL data from one version to another as long as it is MySQL 5.x

If you look at my old post [MySQL upgrade 5.0.88 to latest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39716/mysql-upgrade-5-0-88-to-latest/39763#39763), I handle this situation going to a higher version. With slight modifications, I can make this process go backwards.

**STEP 01** : mysqldump all databases except mysql, information_schema, performance_schema

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -ppassword"
SQLSTMT="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(schema_name SEPARATOR ' ')"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
DBLIST=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}"`
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--single-transaction --routines --triggers --databases ${DBLIST}"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} > Data.sql
```

**STEP 02** : dump the grants as pure SQL commands

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -ppassword"
SQLSTMT="SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';')"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" | mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AN | sed 's/$/;/g' > Grants.sql
```

**STEP 03** load each file into a new MySQL 5.1 Instance

Login to MySQL as root and run

```
mysql> source Data.sql
mysql> source Grants.sql
```

## Give it a Try !!!

### CAVEAT #1

You cannot mysqldump everything and load it into a different version of MySQL because the mysql schema has columns in the mysql.user table specific to a version.

You cannot run [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-upgrade.html) to fix it because you are doing a downgrade.

I have mentioned splitting the grants from the data before

- `Oct 17, 2014` : [Any known issues upgrading from MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.6.21?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80499/any-known-issues-upgrading-from-mysql-5-1-73-to-5-6-21/80503#80503)
- `Apr 11, 2013` : [MySQL upgrade 5.0.88 to latest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39716/mysql-upgrade-5-0-88-to-latest/39763#39763) (Best Reference)
- `Feb 08, 2012` : [will replication from 5.5.20 to 5.0.XX server work?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12509/will-replication-from-5-5-20-to-5-0-xx-server-work/12511#12511)
- `Jul 26, 2011` : [Restoring an old backup to latest MySQL release](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/restoring-an-old-backup-to-latest-mysql-release/4127#4127)

### CAVEAT #2

The solution I posted would be for Linux, but your database is on a Windows machine. So let me rephrase the solution with Windows in mind ...

**STEP 01** : Get the name of every database in the Windows machine (except mysql, information_schema, performance_schema) and dump them. For example, if your databases as db1, db2 and db3, dump them to a text file like this:

```
C:\> mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --routines --triggers --database db1 db2 db3 > Data.sql
```

**STEP 02** : Dump the Grants to a text file

```
C:\> mysql -uroot -ppassword -ANe"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host),''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" > grant_cmds.sql
C:\> mysql -uroot -ppassword -AN < grant_cmds.sql > Grants.sql
```

**STEP 03** : Edit the Grants.sql

Open Grants.sql in notepad and append a semicolon to every line

**STEP 04** load each file into a new MySQL 5.1 Instance

Login to MySQL as root and run

```
mysql> source Data.sql
mysql> source Grants.sql
```

### CAVEAT #3

I have techniques for using MySQL for Windows with mysqldump along with user-defined variables in the Windows shell : [MySQLdump on specific db date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54538/mysqldump-on-specific-db-date/54547#54547)