# How can I mysqldump all databases except the mysql schema In Windows

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I want to backup all 200+ databases on a MySQL server to all-dbs.sql.

I want to exclude the mysql schema.

How can I do that **IN WINDOWS**?

Comment: @basha04 but it works on Windows?

Comment: I used a search engine and found several high quality blog posts which outline the correct methodology to back up MySQL databases on Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any option for mysqldump to ignore databases for backup?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35081/any-option-for-mysqldump-to-ignore-databases-for-backup)

Answer (score 1):

I actually have an old post from December 2013 on how to mysqldump each database into separate files in MS Windows : [MySQLdump on specific db date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54538/mysqldump-on-specific-db-date/54547#54547)

The main point of that post is to get mysql to create the Windows Batch Files. Then, execute the batch files.

Please review the post carefully. It took me a while to come up with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

- Including only your `DATABASE(s)` can be done by specifying just the desired databases on the `mysqldump` command line.
- Skipping a few tables is easy with

> `--ignore-table=name` Do not dump the specified table. To specify more
> than one
> table to ignore, use the directive multiple times, once
> for each table.  Each table must be specified with both
> database and table names, e.g.,
> --ignore-table=database.table.